# Misunderstanding quantifier floats

Tags: syntax, grammatical-subject, quantifiers

I'm reading Core Syntax by Adger and there is an exercise to analyze the following data.

- *The dragons were slain all.
- *The Greeks arrived all.

Now I know the phenomena of floating quantifiers comes from quantifiers being stranded after movement from the specifier of the vP to the specifier of the TP. Yet I don't understand how to show that the above sentences are ungrammatical.

Comment: They're bad because the Qs landed in the wrong place. The canonical target for Q-float (like all adverb placement) is after the first auxiliary, if there is one, otherwise right before the MV. These quantifiers all landed at the end. *_These quantifiers landed at the end all._ Use whatever angels and pinheads you need to express that in Core Syntax.